# Construct a polynomial equation of the least degree with rational coefficient one of root is $\sin 10^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

I want to construct an equation with least degree which root is $\sin 10°$, but I had no idea to find it please add a  tip hint to find the equation.
     I want to find the solution without using the value of $\sin 10°$.

Comment: If you want rational coefficients you might consider $\sin 30$

Comment: Is that really ten *minutes*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hint:* $\sin(3x)=3\sin x -4\sin^3 x$.

Solution:

> For $x=10^\circ$, we get $\frac12 =  3\sin(10^\circ)-4\sin^3(10^\circ)$ and so $\sin(10^\circ)$ is a root $6x-8x^3=1$. By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), this equation has no rational roots. Therefore, $\sin(10^\circ)$ is not rational. Since $3$ is prime, this equation is the one with least degree having $\sin(10^\circ)$  as root.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming degrees were intended.

you are asking about $\cos 80^\circ$ or $\cos \frac{4 \pi}{9}.$

Write $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / 9}.$ Then $$ \omega^6 + \omega^3 + 1 = 0  $$ from which we can calculate that
$$ \omega + \frac{1}{\omega} \; , \; \;  \omega^2 + \frac{1}{\omega^2} \; , \; \;   \omega^4 + \frac{1}{\omega^4} \; , \; \;  $$
are the roots of
$$  x^3 - 3x + 1 \; .   $$
So $2 \cos 80^\circ$ is such a root. You want half, so let $x=2t,$ which solves
$$  8 t^3 - 6 t + 1   $$

=========================================================

Some detail: let us take $\beta = \omega^2 \; .$ Then $\beta^6 + \beta^3 + 1 = \omega^{12} + \omega^6 + 1 = \omega^3 + \omega^6 + 1 = 0.$

Next, $$ \left(\beta + \frac{1}{\beta}\right)^3 = \beta^3 + 3 \beta + 3 \frac{1}{\beta} + \frac{1}{\beta^3}   $$ so that
$$ \left(\beta + \frac{1}{\beta}\right)^3 - 3\left(\beta + \frac{1}{\beta}\right) + 1  = \beta^3 + 1 + \frac{1}{\beta^3} = \frac{\beta^6 + \beta^3 + 1}{\beta^3} = 0.   $$

[image]